# RxJs requests in cycle

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have a list of parameters and for each parameter a request is sent to the server. The number of parameters may vary, so requests are sent in a loop. The question is, how can I send requests for all parameters, wait for a response from all requests and continue executing the program. To do this you need to use RxJS.

```
  private getValuesForEditTariff(parameter: Parameter) {

    if (parameter.dependParams != null && parameter.dependParams.length > 0) {

      let pars: Parameter[] = new Array<Parameter>();
      this.actionEditTariff.groups.forEach(group => {
        pars = pars.concat(group.parameters);
      });

      let locator = (p: Parameter, id: number) => p.id == id;

      let service = this.actionService;
      let action = this.actionEditTariff;

      parameter.dependParams.forEach(parameter => {

        let par = pars.find(p => locator(p, parameter));
        if (par) {

          par.loading = true;

          service.getValues(parameter, pars,action.action, action.actionScheme).subscribe({
            next: (data) => {
              par.values = data;
              par.loading = false;
              console.log("Значения получены");
            },
            error: (error)=> {
              this.message = error.error.message || error.statusText;
              par.loading = false;
              this.showError();
            }
          })
        }
      })
    }
  }
```

I tried to use concatMap, but i dont fugire out how its works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [forkJoin](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin) to wait for all the responses like this

```js
private getValuesForEditTariff(parameter: Parameter) {
  if (parameter.dependParams != null && parameter.dependParams.length > 0) {
    let pars: Parameter[] = new Array<Parameter>();

    this.actionEditTariff.groups.forEach(group => {
      pars = pars.concat(group.parameters);
    });

    const locator = (p: Parameter, id: number) => p.id == id;

    const service = this.actionService;
    const action = this.actionEditTariff;

    const parameters$ = parameter.dependParams.reduce((parameters, parameter) => {
      const par = pars.find(p => locator(p, parameter));

      if (par) {
        par.loading = true;

        parameters.push(
          service.getValues(parameter, pars, action.action, action.actionScheme).pipe(
            tap(() => {
              par.values = data;
              par.loading = false;
              console.log('Значения получены');
            }),
            catchError(() => {
              this.message = error.error.message || error.statusText;
              par.loading = false;
              this.showError();

              return of(null);
            }),
          ),
        );
      }

      return parameters;
    }, []);

    forkJoin(parameters$).subscribe();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but  what is variable "parameters" ? Is it array? Can't find declaration of it

Comment: @denikotin this is the first param passed to the callback of the array reduce method, you can check it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: Ok, can you explain why you use reduce here please. And how you do parameters.push(), if parameters is a number type

Comment: @denikotin The goal is to have an array of observables to pass to `forkJoin`, so I used `reduce` because you are filtering on the condition `if (par)` before sending the request, so you can either use `.reduce()` or `.filter().map()` to get the desired array so `reduce` will do 1 loop over the array instead of 2, and `parameters` is not a number, it is an array that will have the requests that will be sent.

Comment: I got an error that parameters are not an array and can't make push(). But anyway, thank you so much, it really usefull for me, appreciate it.

Comment: @denikotin please try again I updated my answer